# How to convert curl request to HttpClient having --resolve

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a following curl request

```
curl -X POST -D- --insecure -H "ApiKey: $api_key" https://api.myapi.com/service/12345/purge/12345--resolve [http://api.myapi.com:443:11.112.121.194/]api.myapi.com:443:11.112.121.194
```

I want to convert that over to HttpClient.

```
var baseUrl = "https://api.myapi.com";
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUrl) };
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));         
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ApiKey", "api_key");

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, $"service/{12345}/purge/{12345}");
request.Content = new StringContent(null, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

How do I add --resolve parameter to HttpRequest?

Comment: The curl request is not  valid

Comment: I got this request from third party. Is it even possible to emulate "resolve" in c# httpclient?

Comment: The invalid problem is that there needs to be a space before `--resolve`.   For httpclient emulation of `--resolve` you're going to have to do an end run around DNS resolution.